# I can't send email with pywin32 & excel

Tags: python, excel, email, pdf, win32com

I have the following code that reads an existing Excel file, change PDF files, and send emails. Among those things sending emails fuction doesn't work. How can I solve it?

here is How macro works

- 1. Unit to set the path to save Excel file
- 2. Load original file
- 3. Load email info
- 4. Converting Excel to PDF
- 5. Send Emails with PDF Files

number 5 doesn't works :(

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

import pandas as pd
import win32com.client.gencache
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

# 현재 월을 가져오는 라이브러리
import datetime

import time

# 이메일 전송을 위한 PKG
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email.header import Header


# 현재 날짜와 시간 가져오기
current_date = datetime.datetime.now()

# 현재의 년도 가져오기
current_year = current_date.year

# 현재의 월 가져오기
current_month = current_date.month

def AutoPay(RFolder, RFile, MData, mTitle, mMain, mYN):
    global current_date, current_year, current_month
    
    if mYN == True :
        # 내 메일 정보 가져오기
        dfmail = pd.read_excel(MData)

        # 메일 필요 정보 초기화하기
        # 세션 생성
        # s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)    # gmail 이메일 서버
        s = SMTP_SSL('smtp.daum.net', 465)         # 다음 이메일 서버
        # s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.naver.com', 587)    # 네이버 이메일 서버

        #    TLS 보안 시작
        # s.starttls()

        #    로그인 인증
        s.login(dfmail['mail'][0], dfmail['m_pw'][0])

    # 필요 데이터 읽어오기 (판다스)
    dfR = pd.read_excel(RFile, sheet_name = 1)
    dfM = pd.read_excel(RFile, sheet_name = 'Master')
    dfP = pd.read_excel(RFile, sheet_name = 'Private')
    dfR = dfR.merge(dfP, on = '순번')

    # None 값 0으로 대체하기
    dfR = dfR.fillna(0)

    # 필요 데이터 읽어오기 (pywin32, Format)
    excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = False

    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(RFile)
    ws = wb.Sheets('Format')

    # 저장할 폴더 지정
    FPath = os.path.join(RFolder, f'{current_year}년_{current_month}월_급여명세서')
    if not os.path.exists(FPath):
        os.makedirs(FPath)

    def open_folder_in_explorer(folder_path):
        try:
            os.startfile(folder_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print("폴더를 열 수 없습니다:", e)

    # 파일 탐색기에서 폴더 열기
    open_folder_in_explorer(FPath)

    # 인원별 반복문
    for index, row in dfR.iterrows():

        # 첫번째 인원 사명, 이름 정보 입력하기
        ws.Cells(2,2).Value = '지엔아이티'
        ws.Cells(2,4).Value = row['이름_x']

        # 포멧 양식의 값 초기화 하기
        ws.Range("A5:D20").Value = ''

        # 지급 / 공제 값 입력하기
        pnum = 5
        cnum = 5

        for cName in dfR:
            Sep = dfM['구분'].where(dfM['항목'] == cName).dropna()
            # 구분자가 값이 없을때
            if Sep.empty:
                if cName == '비고':
                    ws.Cells(26,1).Value = row[cName]
            # 구분이 지급일 경우
            elif Sep.iloc[0] =="지급" and row[cName] > 0:
                ws.Cells(pnum,1).Value = cName
                ws.Cells(pnum,2).Value = row[cName]
                pnum += 1
            # 구분이 공제일 경우
            elif Sep.iloc[0] =="공제" and row[cName] > 0:
                ws.Cells(cnum,3).Value = cName
                ws.Cells(cnum,4).Value = row[cName]
                cnum += 1

        # PDF 파일로 파일 저장
        FName = '지엔아이티_' + str(row['이름_x']) + '_' + str(current_year) +'년_' + str(current_month) + '월_' + '급여명세서.pdf'
        pwFName = '지엔아이티_' + str(row['이름_x']) + '_' + str(current_year) +'년_' + str(current_month) + '월_' + '급여명세서_잠금파일.pdf'
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, os.path.join(FPath,FName) )

        try:
            with open(os.path.join(FPath, FName), "rb") as in_file:
                input_pdf = PdfReader(in_file)
                output_pdf = PdfWriter()
                
                for page in input_pdf.pages:
                    output_pdf.add_page(page)
                
                output_pdf.encrypt(str(row['PW']))

                with open(os.path.join(FPath, pwFName), "wb") as out_file:
                    output_pdf.write(out_file)
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("오류", "PDF 파일 암호화 과정 중 오류가 발생했습니다. 관리자에게 문의하세요.")
            print("PDF 파일 암호화 중 오류 발생:", e)
        
            if mYN == True :
                # 이메일 발송
                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                msg['Subject'] = mTitle
                msg['From'] = dfmail['mail'][0]
                msg['To'] = row['e-mail']
                msg.attach(MIMEText(mMain))

                f= os.path.join(FPath,pwFName)
                fil = open(f, "rb")

                part = MIMEApplication(
                    fil.read(),
                    Name=basename(f)
                )
                # After the file is closed
                # 파일 이름을 UTF-8로 인코딩하여 설정
                part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = Header(basename(f), 'utf-8').encode())
                msg.attach(part)

                # 메일 보내기
                s.sendmail(dfmail['mail'][0], row['e-mail'], msg.as_string())

        if mYN == True :
            # 이메일 세션 종료
            s.quit()

    try:
        # Excel 파일 닫기
        wb.Close(False)
        # Excel 인스턴스 종료
        excel.Quit()
        # 시간 지연 추가
        time.sleep(1)  # 1초 대기
    except Exception as e:
        print("Excel 관련 오류 발생:", e)

# 폴더경로 바꾸는 버튼을 눌렀을때 업데이트
def onClick(i):
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
    foldName = folder_selected.replace('/','\\')
    if folder_selected:  # 사용자가 폴더를 선택한 경우에만 업데이트
        lbPath[i].config(text=folder_selected)  # 선택한 폴더 경로 업데이트
    df.Detail[i] = foldName
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Master.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Folder', index=False)
    dff.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='File',index=False)
    writer.close()
    return

# 파일경로와 이름 바꾸는 버튼을 눌렀을때 업데이트
def onClickf(i):
    folder_selected = filedialog.askopenfile()
    fileName = folder_selected.name.replace('/','\\')
    lbPathf[i].config(text=fileName)
    dff.Detail[i] = fileName
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Master.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Folder', index=False)
    dff.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='File',index=False)
    writer.close()
    return

# GUI 구성
win = Tk()
win.geometry("580x490")
win.title('자동 개별 급여 명세표 발송기')

df= pd.read_excel("Master/Master.xlsx",sheet_name="Folder", engine = "openpyxl")
dff= pd.read_excel("Master/Master.xlsx",sheet_name="File", engine = "openpyxl")

# 프로그램 Process 안내문구
frame0 = Frame(win, pady=5)
frame0.pack()
Label(frame0, text = '\n[ 프로그램 Process ]\n\n 1. 개별 파일 만들기 → 2. (수정 시) 파일 재생성 or 이메일 전송 → 3. 프로그램 종료', width = 70, anchor = 'w').pack()

# 폴더 경로 설정 GUI
frame1 = Frame(win, pady=5)
frame1.pack()    # 만약, GUI 내에 파일 저장 경로를 보여지게 하고 싶다면 주석처리 해제
lbName = []
lbPath = []
btnPath = []

for i in df.index:
    lbName.append(Label(frame1, text=df.Item[i], width=10))
    lbName[i].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=W)
    lbPath.append(Label(frame1, text=df.Detail[i], width=50, anchor = 'w'))
    lbPath[i].grid(row=i, column=1, sticky=W)
    btnPath.append(Button(frame1, text="Change Path", width=10,command=lambda i=i: onClick(i)))
    btnPath[i].grid(row=i, column=2, sticky=W)


# 파일 경로 설정 GUI
frame2 = Frame(win, pady=5)
frame2.pack()    # 만약, GUI 내에 파일 저장 경로를 보여지게 하고 싶다면 주석처리 해제
lbNamef = []
lbPathf = []
btnPathf = []

for i in dff.index:
    lbNamef.append(Label(frame2, text=dff.Item[i], width=10))
    lbNamef[i].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=W)
    lbPathf.append(Label(frame2, text=dff.Detail[i], width=50, anchor = 'w'))
    lbPathf[i].grid(row=i, column=1, sticky=W)
    btnPathf.append(Button(frame2, text="Change Path", width=10,command=lambda i=i: onClickf(i)))
    btnPathf[i].grid(row=i, column=2, sticky=W)

def check_excel_file(path):
    """파일이 유효한 엑셀 파일인지 확인합니다."""
    if not path.lower().endswith('.xlsx'):
        messagebox.showerror("오류", "유효한 엑셀 파일이 아닙니다. 엑셀 파일을 선택하세요.\n(Master File에서 파일 경로 수정 가능)")
        return False
    try:
        pd.read_excel(path, engine="openpyxl")  # 엑셀 파일인지 확인
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("오류", f"파일을 열 수 없습니다: {e}")
        return False

# 메일 제목 Label
frame3 = Frame(win, pady=7)
frame3.pack()
Label(frame3, text = '메일 제목', width = 70, anchor = 'w').pack()

# 메일 제목 TextBox
frame4 = Frame(win)
frame4.pack()
txtMT = Text(frame4, width = 70, height = 1, padx = 5, pady=5)
txtMT.insert(INSERT, str(current_month) + '월 급여 내역 송부의 건')
txtMT.pack()

# 메일 본문 Label
frame5 = Frame(win, pady=7)
frame5.pack()
Label(frame5, text = '메일 본문', width = 70, anchor = 'w').pack()

# 메일 본문 TextBox
frame6 = Frame(win)
frame6.pack()
txtMM = Text(frame6, width = 70, height = 5, padx = 5, pady=5)

# 현재 날짜와 시간 가져오기
current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
txtMM.insert(INSERT, '안녕하세요. (주)지엔아이티입니다.\n' + str(current_month) + '월 급여 내역을 유첨 파일과 같이 송부 드립니다.\n명세서 파일 비밀번호는 본인의 주민등록번호 뒤 7자리입니다.\n감사합니다.')
txtMM.pack()

# 안내문 or 공지문
frame7 = Frame(win, pady=2)
frame7.pack()
Label(frame7, text = "(본문과 제목의 '월'은 매달 자동으로 입력되므로 수정하지 않으셔도 됩니다.)", width = 70, anchor = 'w').pack()

label = tk.Label(frame7, text="< 진행 상황 >", height = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
label.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

def send_email():
    # 파일 경로가 유효한 엑셀 파일인지 확인
    if not all(check_excel_file(path['text']) for path in lbPathf):
        return
    
    # 작업 중 텍스트 표시
    label.config(text="작업 중...", fg="red", font="Helvetica")
    win.update()

    # 메일 본문 및 메일 제목 가져오기
    mail_subject = txtMT.get(1.0, END).strip()  # 메일 제목 가져오기
    mail_body = txtMM.get(1.0, END).strip()     # 메일 본문 가져오기
    
    # 메일 본문이나 메일 제목이 비어있는지 확인
    if not mail_subject or not mail_body:
        messagebox.showerror("오류", "메일 제목 또는 메일 본문이 비어있습니다. 메일을 발송할 수 없습니다.")
        return

    # 이메일 발송 전 확인 창 띄우기
    confirmation = messagebox.askyesno("이메일 발송 확인", "정말 이대로 이메일을 발송하시겠습니까?\n(예를 누를시, 취소가 불가능합니다!)")
    if not confirmation:
        return  # 사용자가 "아니오"를 선택한 경우 작업 취소

    # 이메일 발송 로직 추가
    # AutoPay 함수 호출 또는 다른 이메일 발송 로직 작성
    AutoPay(lbPath[0]['text'], lbPathf[0]['text'], lbPathf[1]['text'], mail_subject, mail_body, True)

    # 메일 전송 완료 메시지를 표시
    messagebox.showinfo("메일 전송 완료", "메일이 성공적으로 전송되었습니다.")

    # 작업 완료 텍스트 표시
    label.config(text="전송 완료", pady=7, fg="green", font="Helvetica")

    # 버튼 숨기기
    btnSM.grid_forget()

    btnMF.grid_forget()  # 재생성 버튼 숨기기
    btnMFRe.grid_forget()  # 메일 전송 버튼 숨기기

    # 종료 버튼 생성
    btn_exit = Button(frame7, text="프로그램 닫기", width = 20, pady=10, height=1, command=win.destroy)
    btn_exit.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

def create_file():
    # 파일 경로가 유효한 엑셀 파일인지 확인
    if not all(check_excel_file(path['text']) for path in lbPathf):
        return
    
    # 작업 중 텍스트 표시
    label.config(text="작업 중...", fg="red", font="Helvetica")
    win.update()
 
    AutoPay(lbPath[0]['text'], lbPathf[0]['text'], lbPathf[1]['text'], txtMT.get(1.0,END), txtMM.get(1.0,END), False)

    # 메일 전송 완료 메시지를 표시
    messagebox.showinfo("파일 생성 완료", "파일이 성공적으로 생성되었습니다.")

    # 작업 완료 텍스트 표시
    label.config(text="작업 완료", fg="green", font="Helvetica")

    # 버튼 숨기기
    btnMF.grid_forget()

    # "재생성" 버튼 생성
    btnMFRe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

    # "개별 메일 보내기" 버튼 보이기
    btnSM.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

# 실행 버튼 GUI
frame7 = Frame(win, pady=5)       # Row of buttons
frame7.pack()

# Keywork Change 버튼
btnMF = Button(frame7, text="개별 파일 만들기", width = 30, pady=5, command=create_file)
btnMF.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

btnSM = Button(frame7, text="개별 메일 보내기 (확정)", width = 30, pady=5, height=2, command=send_email, fg="red")

# 재생성 버튼 (초기에는 숨김)
btnMFRe = Button(frame7, text="개별 파일 재생성하기 \n (수정되었다면 덮어쓰기됩니다.)", width=30, height=2, pady=5, command=create_file)

win.mainloop()
```

Here is error code.

`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, os.path.join(FPath,FName) )
File "C:\Users\ZNIT\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.12\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\_Worksheet.py", line 114, in ExportAsFixedFormat  
  return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(3175, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((3, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Type
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, '예외가 발생했습니다.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', '문서가 저장되지 않았습니다.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2147018887), None)`

Have a good day



What I tried
- Check the absolute path
- Shut down Excel
- and so on...

What I expected
- Send Email successfuly
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I wonder how i solve this problem. help me :(

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what were you saying. what does "you need to capture your output" means?? Do I have to capture something to you??